# Swaping columns of numpy array in all rows but the first one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

Given a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(4*7).reshape([4, 7])

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]])
```

I can apply slicing to swap the second and third columns by:

```
a[:, [0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

array([[ 0,  2,  1,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  9,  8, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 16, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 23, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27]])
```

But, can I use slices to swap the second and third columns for all rows but the first one? The expected output would be:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  9,  8, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 16, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 23, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27]])
```

Comment: @Divakar, you are right. Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `in-situ` edit, we can use flipping after slicing out the two columns -

```
a[1:,1:3] = a[1:,2:0:-1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [556]: a = np.arange(4*7).reshape([4, 7])

In [557]: a
Out[557]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]])

In [559]: a[1:,1:3] = a[1:,2:0:-1]

In [560]: a
Out[560]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  9,  8, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 16, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 23, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27]])
```

For columns that are two-step apart, use a stepsize of `2` to assign (LHS) and `-2` to select (RHS). Hence, for column IDs `1` & `3` -

```
In [577]: a = np.arange(4*7).reshape([4, 7])

In [578]: a
Out[578]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]])

In [579]: a[1:,1:4:2] = a[1:,3:0:-2]

In [580]: a
Out[580]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7, 10,  9,  8, 11, 12, 13],
       [14, 17, 16, 15, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 24, 23, 22, 25, 26, 27]])
```

Another method would be with explicit column numbered indexing -

```
a[1:,[1,2]] = a[1:,[2,1]]
```

Note that this creates a copy with `a[1:,[2,1]]` and as such would be less memory efficient than the first method.

Comment: Doesn't the slicing method create a copy as well? Otherwise it wouldn't work, no?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Nope. Check with `np.shares_memory(a,a[1:,2:0:-1])`.

Comment: Not sure this test is conclusive, since as I understand it the copy is only triggered once numpy detects you are doing some in-place assignment from the same memory.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Don't think I understood your point there, but just to elaborate the way I see it is - In second method, `a[1:,[2,1]]` creates an array (intermediate array) separate from `a`. Then , assigns into `a`. In the first method, `a[1:,2:0:-1]` is extracted off `a` and assigned into `a`.  There could be memory buffers involved on top of these (I am not sure on this), but those would be part of both methods and I am not counting that one.

Comment: Hm. I'm too lazy to look at the source (where's @hpaulj when you need him? ;-)) but I'd have thought that buffering is only done if necessary, which it isn't when an intermediate has already been created.

Comment: @PaulPanzer If you are really feeling desperate, one way would be creating a huge array, do the swaps and watch system monitor.

Comment: `a = np.arange(30*10**7).reshape(-1, 3); b = np.arange(21*10**7).reshape(-1, 3); del b` (ok) `a[...] = a[:, ::-1]` (MemoryError) `a = np.arange(24*10**7).reshape(-1, 3); a[...] = a[:, [2,1,0]]` (ok)

Comment: @PaulPanzer To conclusively reach conclusions, I think we need to run both methods and profile them separately. Might do it later.

Comment: @Divakar I think this snippet is even more concise: `a[1:, 1:] = a[1:, :0:-1]` :)  Since OP says all rows but first; Making it more generic is good!

Comment: @Divakar, thank you for your answers. Do you think it is possible to obtain the same output without editing/changing the initial array values?

Comment: @saltimbanqui If you meant not in-situ edit, i.e. output as a separate one, make a copy with `.copy()` and use the proposed solutions with that copy.